# TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined, cant call some value from array in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

im doing studying again about reactjs, got problem at here and i think it was weird ..

```
componentDidMount(){
fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response =>{
        const {memes} = response.data
        this.setState({allMemeImgs: memes})
      })
      console.log(this.state.allMemeImgs)
}
```

after iam fetching some value from that API and store at state type array try do call array like this

```
{console.log(this.state.allMemeImgs)}
```

[try 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrCBb.png)

```
{console.log(this.state.allMemeImgs[0])}
```

[try 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDobM.png)

and then when i need url value it will be throw error

```
{console.log(this.state.allMemeImgs[0].url)}
```

[try 3 and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8Lp7.png)

[console log for response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELsaF.png)

Comment: It is bad practice to setState in any lifecycle method, and it may lead to errors. I suggest you create a separate function that sets the state, and then call it inside the componentDidMount().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, your array is in memes so,

```
{console.log(this.state.allMemeImgs.meme[0].url)}
```

Also please use await while fetching data so that it will wait for the response before going further

```
await fetch("https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response =>{
        const {memes} = response.data
        this.setState({allMemeImgs: memes})
      })
```

Comment: thank you , its work , just need use async function and await

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the response if it is array or not. Can you post the response here once?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your render method, you have to check if all the data exists before going deeper into the object. Try adding this check.

```js
if (!response.data) {
  return null;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: `componentDidMount` is a lifecycle method that runs **after** the first render. In between the first render and fetching data, `allMemeImgs` is `undefined` or `null` or an empty array (depending on how you initialized the state).

If you watch the log of your first two tries carefully, you will probably notice `null` or `undefined` somewhere above your desired output.

Therefore, always ensure the data is not null before rendering them. The most convenient way is to use the **Short-circuit evaluation** like this

```
condition && renderThisIfTrue
```